# .htaccess query string removal - can't figure out how

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

re,

I can't figure out how to remove a query string from URL, redirect to another URL and pass that query string to a PHP script:

```
RewriteRule ^shopping/paypal/([0-9A-Za-z]*)?$ https://myserver.com/shopping/? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^shopping/$ php/shopping.php [QSA,L]
```

Basically, when I get the following request:

```
https://myserver.com/shopping/paypal/?token=EC-3L827812DL640424T
```

I want it to redirect to:

```
https://myserver.com/shopping/
```

and since /shopping/ is a "virtual" directory, I want it to pass the token key and map to:

```
php/shopping.php?token=EC-3L827812DL640424T
```

Please advise. Thanks!

Comment: Without storing the token in e.g. a session before redirecting to /shopping/ I don't believe this is possible since you chuck the data you need for the second redirect...

Comment: Thanks. How would I set a cookie on original request, then do a redirect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you use an intermediate PHP script like this:

```
RewriteRule ^shopping/paypal/([0-9A-Za-z]*)?$ php/savetoken.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^shopping/$ php/shopping.php [L]
```

where in savetoken.php:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['token'] = $_GET['token'];
    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently"); //without this PHP issues a 302
    header('Location: shopping/');
    exit;
```

Then in shopping.php you start the session and read the token value from it (and maybe delete it from the session, to prevent it from popping up in the future)

Comment: Would it note take a performance hit if I were to use PHP to set a cookie and then do a redirect?

Comment: From the browser's point of view a redirect implies a single one-time (per page) additional roundtrip to the server - dependent on how fare away the visitor is (e.g. crossing the Atlantic is one tenth of a second).

Comment: For the server this means it has to run an additional script, write the session file to disk and send a session cookie along with the response. Writing to disk is the most expensive part; if you're in the range of thousands of pages per second running a bytecode cache like APC (and using the same to store sessions) would be called for, otherwise don't bother - just make sure you haven't bottlenecks elsewhere. Cookies? Zero, nobody even measures them.